# Make attachment pages require a base url

Tags: permalinks, uploads, urls, media, slug

If I upload an image with the filename `8.jpg` then the permalink becomes `http://www.example.com/8` -- which I really don't want. How can I make attachments use their mime type as a base for the url? `http://example.com/image/8`?

```
add_action('init', function(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'media', EP_PERMALINK | EP_ATTACHMENT| EP_PAGES  );
    flush_rewrite_rules(true);
} );
```

I'm not really sure how endpoints work but I can turn `/media/8` into a post...

Comment: Just a small hack: you could also make a private page called `image` and attach all your unattached images to that page which gives you `http://example.com/image/8`. Im sure there's a way to alter permalinks in a way you requested but I haven't worked with permalinks yet.

Comment: Is this common? I can't count on my clients to clean their filenames before upload but the unique slug - for a stupid name like `8`, `8-2`, `8-3`, seems ridiculous. More so if the name conflicts with an unpublished page. I'm working on side-loading images from DropBox so who knows how people name their images.

Comment: Im not sure, I've done this job only for myself so far. What is the site used for? Image permalinks are very important? My site is full of images but there's no way to access attachment page (to see those ugly permalinks) unless user knows exact permalink. About the name conflicts.. Im not 100% sure but Im fairly sure that WordPress is bulletproof in that area: same name attachments, pages, posts, slugs etc gets indexes added to the name.

Comment: I really don't need attachment pages. In fact, I think I'm using the template_redirect to close off major portions of that kinda of functionality. The side-loading plugin is just to give an easier/faster way to upload images in bulk -- which makes me now see crappy filenames on a fresh WP install.

Comment: You aren't actually talking about filenames. You are talking about attachment page addresses. But what addresses do you want? `http://example.com/image/8.jog` is hardly better. And nothing generated is going to be much better than "crappy" if your clients won't name their images properly.

Comment: I guess to me, a namespace for media is better than at the root

Answer (score 4):

Endpoints are for adding extra query vars to existing routes, I think you just want a vanilla rewrite rule here:

```
function wpd_media_image_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^image/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?post_type=attachment&name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_media_image_rewrite_rule' );
```

You might want to loop over valid mime-types there and add a rule for each. You also need to flush rewrites for this to start working, but don't use `flush_rewrite_rules` on init like in your example above. Rules should only be flushed when they change. A quick way to flush them is to just visit the permalinks settings page.

You'll also need to filter at least `attachment_link` to output the correct URL for unattached media, like:

```
function wpd_media_image_att_link( $link, $post_id ){
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if( 0 == $post->post_parent ){
        $link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( 'image/' . $post->post_name ) );
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wpd_media_image_att_link', 10, 2 );
```

Here we check if the attachment doesn't have a parent, because if it's attached to a post, it would be a child of the parent post. You could also check mime-type here and make the `image/` part dynamic according to type.

There's also the `wp_get_attachment_link` function which may need a filter, if that's used in the template somewhere. I don't think core admin uses that function anywhere though, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Would this mean both `example.com/media/8/` and `example.com/8/` point to the same content?

Comment: Adding extra rules will technically mean that you can access it from two different URLs, however, filtering `attachment_link` will result in only one uniform format of link pointing to that content, including the canonical link which tells search engines where to index it. In practice you shouldn't have any issues with this, like duplicate content.

Comment: I can't see it being a problem unless for some reason there's no canonical set. In such cases it might be better to filter the existing rewrite rule?

Comment: The canonical URL will be whatever link the API outputs for given content. As long as you always generate URLs to content via the API, it should be a non-issue.